# Why didn’t Chewie dine? (in-universe explanation)

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

One fine evening by a roaring fire, Chewbacca is ready to

> feast on roasted porg. He has two at least. The (still living) porgs seem to be distraught

that he would eat (although they do seem much more

> upset about the prospect of their departed family and friends being chewed on than about them being offed in the first place).

From Return of the Jedi we know that Chewie is an enthusiastic carnivore whose appetite sometimes clouds his sense of caution and self-preservation.

Did he really start having

> second thoughts about his intended pulled-porg meal just because they gave him puppy-dog eyes?

Comment: I read the title as "Why didn't Chewie *die*". Spoilers! :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor Same here XD

Comment: possibly connect to the trope of no one ever actually taking a bite of their food when "eating" in films and tv shows.

Comment: does this need spoiler tags?

Comment: My personal theory is that he *did* eat the porg, and loved it so much that he decided that he needed a whole flock of them on the Falcon so that he can dine on them whenever he likes. Any affection is just good animal husbandry.

Comment: I think you just have to accept the out of universe. That saved a million dollars in animation

Comment: My theory is that he gave some roast porg to the one looking at him with doggy eyes and they were both happy; )

Comment: @GarretGang aaaah... they were crying because he wasn't *sharing*! _Now_ I understand :D

Answer (score 10):

The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) *seems* to confirm that Chewie ate at least one porg during his time on the island (or else how could he have formed an opinion about the "tastiest part").

[image]

That being said, other canon sources (such as the film's novelisation) clearly imply that he didn't eat because he felt sad about his actions.

> On the other side of the fire a whole family of porgs was huddled together, staring up at him.
>   The Wookiee roared and the porgs fled into the darkness. Checking to make sure he hadn’t missed any stragglers, he turned back to his dinner—only to find he’d lost his appetite. Something about the way the porgs had looked at him made him feel like he’d done a bad thing. But he’d only been hungry.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

and

> Chewbacca roasted his dinner outside the ship. He grabbed a spit from the campfire and brought the blackened slab on it to his lips. Before he bit into the meat, an uncooked member of its species, one of Ahch-To’s little avians, waddled up from a group and stared at him innocently. Chewbacca snarled, showing fangs, and the other avians around him shot in all directions, much faster than they appeared capable of moving.
>   **The Wookiee returned to eat his meal, but then dropped it with a guilty whine. Luke smiled as he walked up the Falcon’s boarding ramp. Chewbacca’s heart always won out over his hunger.**
>
> <sub><sup>[the Last Jedi: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

And as we see in [Chewie and the Porgs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewie_and_the_Porgs), he eventually grew to love the porgs.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, Chewbacca is definitely a softy. He plays all tough on the outside but inside he's just a big teddy bear.

Comment: This doesn't say that Chewie ate that porg. Just that some wookie (probably many) ate some porgs at some point.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I'll amend it as soon as you show me evidence of *any other Wookiee coming into contact with any other porg*.

Comment: @Valorum absence of evidence!=evidence of absence.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Under normal circumstances I'd agree with you, except that I *can* provide evidence of a wookiee coming into contact with a porg.

Comment: @Valorum - but you can't provide evidence taht Chewie was the first/only one. Other than (well, of the copious Wookies in 'real life', 0.000000000001% shown in canon materials haven't had contacts with Porg. But we don't know enough about the other 99.9999999%)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Porgs are native to Ahch-To and wookiees probably weren't regular visitors to the island over the years.

Comment: @Valorum - there were Wookie Jedi before. So it's not out of range of probable

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Now you're just being pedantic. He clearly ate one because they're yummy and he's got all the willpower of a toddler

Comment: @Valorum - the way it was depicted in the film was he was all set to eat one and didn't even start before the Porgs guilted him into stopping. And no i'm not being pedantic I'm being logical.

Answer (score 7):

### We don't know whether Chewie ate or not.

While it's likely that Chewbacca didn't finish his meal after the disappointing moan he gave as Luke was boarding the ship, it's also possible that after scaring off the last porg he went along with his meal. (I mean he needs to eat something)

This will likely become more clear in March when the novelisations are released or if a screenplay is released as they normally provide more details on the matter.