# What award did Leia give Chewie, Han and Luke?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

What award/medal is this -
[image]
I have been searching [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Awards) to try and find what medal this is, but i have not found it, does anyone know what this medal/award was and why it would be given (eg- bravery, serving in the battle of Yavin)?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_Award_Ceremony

Comment: Chewie never got a medal :( And he didn't get to eat the meat in ROTJ :( And he never got to eat his roast Porg in TLJ. Poor Chewie!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To It appears Chewie was also given a medal according to the [wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Medal_of_Bravery) - > _"Chewbacca was also presented with such a medal, though not during the public ceremony."_

Comment: To me, the only canon ceremony will always be when [Chewbacca was presented with his medal by Carrie Fisher at the 1997 MTV Movie Awards, as part of his lifetime achievement award](https://thenostalgiablog.com/2014/05/29/that-time-mtv-gave-chewbacca-the-lifetime-achievement-award/).

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - There's evidence that he got to eat at least one porg before the others guilted him into eating fish

Comment: @Valorum - i remember seeing him NOT eating that one he was holding. Did you get an unpublished early copy of junior novelization or something? :P

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - The Visual Dictionary indicates that Chewie ate enough to have a preference over which part is the tastiest; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176501/why-didn-t-chewie-dine-in-universe-explanation/176510#176510

Comment: Participation trophies.

Comment: @Möoz - Yay. Everyone's a winner!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To, interesting fact: in the *novelization*, Chewbacca gets his medal. See https://www.tor.com/2013/01/24/weird-differences-between-the-first-star-wars-movie-and-its-preceding-novelization/.

Comment: @Möoz And they made Han Solo a general after his "little maneuver" at the Battle of Yavin

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The (canon) storybook [Princess Leia: Royal Rebel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Leia:_Royal_Rebel) names it as the

> *"**Medal of Bravery**"*
>
> [image]

Interestingly, the old [Star Wars Encylopedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia) names it as the

> **"Medal of Yavin"**
>
> [image]

And it's also been called the medal of valor (note the small m and v) and medal for bravery in various (now Legends) stories.

Comment: `The (canon) storybook` _shade was thrown_.

Comment: @Möoz - If a thing's worth doing, it's worth doing with a book written for toddlers.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to JohnP, I have found the answer. The medal is the [Medal of Bravery](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Medal_of_Bravery)-

[image: Picture of the Medal of Bravery]

As quoted from Wookieepedia:

> The Medal of Bravery was an award given for heroic efforts by the Rebel
>   Alliance.

Chewbacca, Han and Luke are the only receivers of the medal.

Comment: _Hey, do you recall those five big, shinny, expensive medals I told you to build_ just in case _? Well, we need three of them ASAP - who was just wasting the kingdom's budget, once again?_

Comment: @mgarciaisaia For all we know these were made of scrap metal. Even if they weren't, it's rather unlikely that the material and production costs of the medal were in any way significant compared to the cost of the actual festivities surrounding the awarding of the medal, unless they were made out of unobtainium or something.

Comment: @Cubic How can I *not* love this site with people like you around?

Comment: They thought it was made of space-chocolate, but alas it was not. (Chewie ate his anyway.)