# What's this round medallion from the "Rise of Skywalker" trailer?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, the-rise-of-skywalker

This round medallion is held by someone in the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoGwf-vOEYM). It looks familiar but I can't place it.

Is it something from existing *Star Wars* lore?

[image: Strange round medallion]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What award did Leia give Chewie, Han and Luke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179560/what-award-did-leia-give-chewie-han-and-luke) - not the same video, but unless I'm missing something, it's the same medal

Comment: I suppose it had to be.. Well played.

Comment: Though I'd argue this is a different question albeit one with the same answer. I'll leave it to the mods.

Comment: It feels like a dupe to me. My answer answers this one without amendment.

Comment: If you have to know the answer to the new question to have even a hope of finding the old question, guess what folks: it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: (Or, to put it another way, y'all have assumed you know the answer. But what if you're wrong? You've bypassed all the site tools that would allow quality-checking the answer you've forced onto this question.)

Comment: Yeah, this is not a duplicate.  This answer to *this* question is:  "It is one of the medals given at the end of *Episode IV.*"  That may be an obvious answer, but I don't think the questioner knew it.  The other question asks about what was the meaning/origin of the medals, which is something different.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't know either, but I searched for  `[star-wars] medal` and the dupe-target was the second result. Dupe-closed asks "what's this medal", medal is the same, looked dupey. Just because it's not the same shot doesn't mean it's not a dupe IMHO

Comment: @Martha - In the (mind-bogglingly unlikely) incidence that it turns out not to be the Medal of Bravery, we can always reopen the question.

Comment: @Valorum: that's not how StackExchange works. (And the fact that the other question's accepted answer is by you adds an element of conflict of interest to your continuing insistence on keeping this question closed.)

Comment: @Martha - Actually that's precisely how Stack Exchange works. When two questions are fundamentally the same ("*What is this thing?"* vs. "*What is this thing?*") then we close one as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Valorum: except they're *not* asking about the same "thing". It's "what is this object in the trailer for a 2019 movie?" vs. "What type of award did the characters in this 42-year-old movie get?". The answer to the latter is "medal of bravery". The answer to the former is "well, it looks very similar to the medal given out in the original movie, but we can't be certain until the movie comes out". Note that for this question, the nature of the medal is 100% irrelevant, while for the old question, the nature of the medal is what is being asked about.

Comment: @Martha - At its heart, the question is an object identification question. Now, I can see lots of things you could ask that would make it be not a dupe ("*Do we know who this medal belongs to?"*, for example) but that's not what OP asked.

Comment: And back to the question of how Stack Exchange is supposed to work, how exactly do you imagine your blithe "we can always reopen the question" play out? How would an average user tell the system, hey, waitasec, this answer is wrong? Downvoting your answer on the question it actually belongs with wouldn't signify anything about this question. The average user can't vote to reopen. What are they supposed to do? Bottom line is, *you're making the site worse, not better*.

Comment: @Martha The fact that the OP wrote "It looks familiar, but I can't place it," and "Is it something from existing *Star Wars* lore?" make Valorum's answer to the question linked as dupe pretty useful. I get the principled place you are coming from, but this is pretty a pretty gray example. Maybe a pick your battles time? Anywho...

Comment: @Lexible: I've learned to simply not visit this site's admin tools, because all it'd do is drive up my blood pressure. So I only fight this site's actively-harmful non-duplicate closing if I happen to encounter it.

Comment: @Martha - I would argue that your constant attempts to reopen questions that are clearly off topic are what is *"making the site worse, not better."* since we end up with a bunch of unneeded duplicate questions. But hey, now I can earn double rep for posting the same answer twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The (canon) storybook [Princess Leia: Royal Rebel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Princess_Leia:_Royal_Rebel) names it as the

> *"**Medal of Bravery**"*
>
> [image]

Interestingly, the old [Star Wars Encylopedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia) names it as the

> **"Medal of Yavin"**
>
> [image]

And it's also been called the medal of valor (note the small m and v) and medal for bravery in various (now Legends) stories.

Comment: The center of that image doesn't match the object in the trailer. It could just be a lack of sufficient resolution, or it could be that it's just a sketch, but that image alone is merely suggestive, not conclusive. (And the text is totally irrelevant, because there's nothing in the trailer to compare it to.)

Comment: You are, of course, more than welcome to go complain to [Scholastic](https://www.scholastic.co.uk/) that the artist they hired isn't very good.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like one of the medals Leia gives out at the end of *A New Hope*. Whether it's Luke's, Han's, or someone else's, we don't know, but the similarities are pretty apparent.

Here's Master Replica's version of the medal:
[image: Medal of Yavin]

The image from the trailer doesn't look as "clean", i.e. it's obviously hand-made, while the replica is obviously machine-made, but they're clearly intended to be the same medal.

Comment: I believe that the original medals *were* handmade, or at least hand-cast in resin; Master Replicas' was cleaned up and made prettier because people expected it, but it's nice that the one in RoS looks closer to the original.