# Whose Medal of Yavin did Chewbacca get, and how did the giver procure it?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, we see Chewbacca receiving a [Medal of Bravery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/209030/19561) (previously known as a Medal of Yavin), similar to the ones Luke Skywalker and Han Solo received at the end of *A New Hope*.

> He gets the medal from Maz Kanata, after the Battle of Exegol.

Since she seems to have a knack for finding significant objects, is this either Han's or Luke's medal? If so, how did she procure it?

Comment: It belonged to a pilot called Pandah Rhing. He was squadron mates with Ret T'conn and Ploh T'Hole

Comment: I don't recall the ending right now.... I assume he received it in an award ceremony? Similar to the one where Han and Luke received theirs? If so then almost certainly it was a new medal not previously owned by any other person.

Comment: Edit I did a little googling and see it was NOT at an award ceremony. She just passed on a medal to him. I did see one mention on Looper.com.... "Kevin Shinick's new Star Wars novel Force Collector, it's revealed that Han Solo gave his New Hope medal to Maz to "pay for a drink," telling her that it belonged to him when it was actually — wait for it — Luke Skywalker's.

Read More: https://www.looper.com/180919/the-meaning-behind-chewbaccas-medal-in-rise-of-skywalker/?utm_campaign=clip"  In any case, it probably IS either Luke, or Han's medal. (I am sure she thought it was Han's

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We would suppose (reading the official novelisation) that it was ***Han's*** Medal of Bravery...

> Chewie was lifting Rose off her feet when Finn saw Maz interrupt.
> “Chewie!” she called, motioning for the Wookiee to bend over. “This is
> for you.” He got down on one knee, and when they were of a height, she
> placed Han’s Medal of Bravery in Chewie’s hand and closed his huge
> fingers around it. “He’d want you to have it,” she added.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

... But it was revealed in *[Star Wars: Force Collector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_Collector)* that is was, in fact ***Luke's*** [Medal of Bravery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179571/20774), awarded to him after the Battle of Yavin. Han Solo swiped it (presumably after Luke left it lying around on the Falcon!), then used it to pay his bar tab to Maz Kanata.

> He tried to obey. “Two men. One taller, with darker hair. One smaller and younger. This belonged to…it belonged to Skywalker.” That name again! “It was put on his neck…around his neck. A woman put it there. She had dark hair, in a long braid. There was a battle, and he was a hero. It was given to him for bravery, and in thanks for his service.”
>
> Maz interrupted, “Wait. You say it was Skywalker’s? Are you sure?”
>
> ...
>
> “Karr,” she said, using his name at last. “What I’m trying to say is that the swindler swindled me. He told me that the medal was his own, but he gave me his friend’s instead. They all fought at the Battle of Yavin and were rewarded together—along with a very handsome Wookiee who would never cheat me in such a fashion, nor would he allow it to occur if he’d been aware of it. We’re very fond of one another, and he would not treat me so badly. Don’t let anyone tell you different.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Force Collector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_Collector)</sup></sub>